# File gets corrupted when sent over TCP Socket using Java Data(I/O)Stream

Tags: java, file, sockets, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I am trying to send a file with Java TCP socket I/O Stream from **Client to Server**. I am using `Data(Input|Output)Stream` in this process.

With every packet of file buffer, I want to send extra information (a `Long`) as HEADER to every `buffer`. I intend to use that info later for controlling I/O Streams.

Everything Works fine for the Following Codes (Without sending extra info (the `long`)):

**Client** :
`out` is `DataOutputStream` from socket `OutputStream`

```java
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(data.getFile()));

            out.writeUTF(file.getName());
            out.writeLong(file.length());

            int n;
            long currentProgress = 0, totalProgress = file.length();

            while ( (n =in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) ) != -1) {
//                out.writeLong(123456);
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                out.flush();

                currentProgress += n;
            }

            in.close();
```

**Server** : `in` is `DataInputStream` from socket `InputStream`

```java
        String fileName = in.readUTF();
        long fileSize = in.readLong();

        File file = new File(fileName);

        try {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        } catch (NullPointerException ignore) {}

        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int n;

        for (long sizeToRead = fileSize;
                     sizeToRead > 0; sizeToRead -= n) {

//            in.readLong();
            n = in.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, sizeToRead));
            if (n==-1) break;


            bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }

        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
        bufferedOutputStream.close();
```

Everything just works fine now, but when I uncomment these two lines:

> `//                out.writeLong(123456);`

> `//            in.readLong();`

**(*Big*) files get corrupted**, I do not understand why this is happening as I am sending and receiving in order.

`BUFFER_SIZE` is currently 512kb (512*1024)

[*This is my first question in StackOverflow, sorry if I have represented my question poorly, Thank You*]

Comment: ***(Big) files get corrupted***  What's a "big" file?  How do you know you're passing the file size properly?  Have you verified the size is correct on the receiving side?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work, as long as you deploy the code correctly, but why on earth *are* you writing 123456 in the first place? This is the time to send data, not constants, or even `long` variables. NB You don't need such enormous buffers. You'll find that 8192 doesn't make it perceptibly slower. Don't flush inside loops, and flush before close is redundant.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Sending 12345 was just a test, if the test had been passed, I would have continued.
Thanks for the advice of not using flush inside loop.

Comment: @AndrewHenle & MarquisofLorne
I think I have found the problem. After running the program through debugger I found that
> Cycle of READ  and WRITE is not same
Read Cycle much less than the write cycle. As loops continues, readLong continues reading from the buffer which eventually corrupts data from from file (missing data).

Thanks everyone.